# Saturn Datepicker dynamic rangeMode props

Tags: angular, datepicker, date-range

I have a sat-datepicker in angular 8 with rangemode prop dynamic, its works when rangeMode is false and change to true, but it’s doesn’t works vice versa, if i selected a range date and later i want select a sngle date when rangeMode is false, throw this error

```
ERROR TypeError: date.clone is not a function
at MomentDateAdapter.push../node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/esm5/material-moment-adapter.es5.js.MomentDateAdapter.clone (material-moment-adapter.es5.js:212)
at MomentDateAdapter.push../node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/esm5/material-moment-adapter.es5.js.MomentDateAdapter.isValid (material-moment-adapter.es5.js:395)
at MomentDateAdapter.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js.DateAdapter.sameDate (core.es5.js:711)
at SatDatepickerInput.set [as value] (saturn-datepicker.js:4409)
at SafeSubscriber._next (saturn-datepicker.js:4329)
at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
at Subject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, i'll answer if i find a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, its kinda ugly but it works like a charm. Duplicate
this file

> node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/fesm5/material-moment-adapter.js

I copied it in a patch directory in my root app folder. Edit this file at line 94

```
MomentDateAdapter.prototype.clone = function (date) {
    try {
      return date.clone().locale(this.locale);
    } catch (e) {
      return moment(date).clone().locale(this.locale);
    }
};
```

Then edit your angular.json file

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter/fesm5/material-moment-adapter.js",
    "with": "patch/material-moment-adapter.js"
  }
],
```